# Problemwith geometric figures calculator

Tags: php, html, class, math, methods

First of all guys, sorry for english, not my native language

I am doing a geometric figures calculator (Triangle, rectangle and square) so, i can only use PHP and HTML. My problem is when I clicked the input with value 'Calcular' (in the form inside $formularioTriangulo variable) is not giving me the result, is refreshing the page.

```
<?php

class Calculando{   

    public function recibiendo(){   


    $figura = isset($_POST['figuraGeometrica']) ? $_POST['figuraGeometrica'] : NULL; 

        switch($figura){            
            case 'triangulo': //triangle case

            $formularioTriangulo = "<h3>Calcular Area del Triangulo</h3><br>

            <form method='POST'>
            <table>
                <tr><td>Introduzca la base del triangulo: <input type='text' name='base'></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Introduzca la altura del triangulo: <input type='text' name='altura'></td></tr>
                <tr><td><input type='submit' value='calcular'></td></tr>
            </table>
            </form>
            ";

            $base = isset($_POST['base']) ? $_POST['base'] : NULL;
            $altura = isset($_POST['altura']) ? $_POST['altura'] : NULL;                

            echo $formularioTriangulo;
            $result = ($base * $altura)/2;

            echo $result;

            break;

            case 'rectangulo': //rectangle case

            break;

            case 'cuadrado': //square case

            break;          
        }
    }
}   

$llamar = new Calculando();
$llamar->recibiendo();

?>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Calculadora de Medidas</title>
</head>


<body>
<br><br>
<table>
<form method="POST">

    <h3>Calculadora de Figuras Geom&eacute;tricas</h3>
    <tr>
        <select name="figuraGeometrica">
            <option value="na"></option>
            <option value="triangulo">Triangulo</option>
            <option value="rectangulo">Rectangulo</option>
            <option value="cuadrado">Cuadrado</option>
        </select>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Enviar"></td>
    </tr>

</form>
<table>
</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

So it seems your Switch statement is false unless the post variable 'figuraGeometrica' has a value. Once you post your triangle's data via the form that's generate from the first post, you must also post the 'figuraGeometrica' for triangle, otherwise you'll skip the entire statement.

Here's a fix for your existing code to get the triangle working using a hidden form value. If you're going about it this way, you'll need to do this for the other shapes when you generate their forms, but change the value to the corresponding shape.  :)

```
<?php

class Calculando{   

    public function recibiendo(){   


    $figura = isset($_POST['figuraGeometrica']) ? $_POST['figuraGeometrica'] : NULL; 

        switch($figura){            
            case 'triangulo': //triangle case

            $formularioTriangulo = "<h3>Calcular Area del Triangulo</h3><br>

            <form method='POST'>
            <input type='hidden' name='figuraGeometrica' value='triangulo'>
            <table>
                <tr><td>Introduzca la base del triangulo: <input type='text' name='base'></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Introduzca la altura del triangulo: <input type='text' name='altura'></td></tr>
                <tr><td><input type='submit' value='calcular'></td></tr>
            </table>
            </form>
            ";

            $base = isset($_POST['base']) ? $_POST['base'] : NULL;
            $altura = isset($_POST['altura']) ? $_POST['altura'] : NULL;                

            echo $formularioTriangulo;
            $result = ($base * $altura)/2;

            echo $result;

            break;

            case 'rectangulo': //rectangle case

            break;

            case 'cuadrado': //square case

            break;          
        }
    }
}   

$llamar = new Calculando();
$llamar->recibiendo();

?>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Calculadora de Medidas</title>
</head>


<body>
<br><br>
<table>
<form method="POST">

    <h3>Calculadora de Figuras Geom&eacute;tricas</h3>
    <tr>
        <select name="figuraGeometrica">
            <option value="na"></option>
            <option value="triangulo">Triangulo</option>
            <option value="rectangulo">Rectangulo</option>
            <option value="cuadrado">Cuadrado</option>
        </select>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Enviar"></td>
    </tr>

</form>
<table>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: So you are saying to input form to stay visible when figuraGeometrica is equals to the case in the switch?

Comment: Initially I only posted the variable that contained the code to draw your form properly. To avoid confusion I'll edit it and include a working version of your original post.

Comment: `<input type='hidden' name='figuraGeometrica' value='triangulo'>`